# How to calculate Euclidean distance in R for n-dimensions?

Tags: r, function, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to write a function which calculates Euclidean distance between two points across n-dimensions.

I have the following code:

```
euc_dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
```

This works between two points, `x1` and `x2`. However, I'm trying to do this for n-dimensions between the two points.

So for instance, in Python, it works with:

```
def euc_distance(p, q):
    return math.sqrt(sum((px - qx) ** 2 for px, qx in zip(p, q)))
```

I.e. you can input with e.g. three dimensions (between two points):

```
euc_distance([2, 1, 4], [4, 9, 8])
```

How can I edit my R code to do the same thing?

Comment: have a look at `?dist` : `dist(rbind(c(0,3,0), c(4,0,0)))`

Comment: Thank you - but I'm trying to write the function instead of using `dist`. Any advice? @GKi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, you can use the function `dist()`, which returns the euclidean distance between the rows, regardless of the number of columns (dimensions). Alternatively, if you want to use your function, you can do this:

```
euc_dist <- function(x1, x2){
 return(sqrt(sum((x1 - x2)^2)))
}
```

Don't forget the `return()` at the end of an R function, it's a common "mistake" that will bring unnecessary headaches
And when passing the input to the function, do it like this instead, as it is the correct way of working with vectors in R:

```
euc_dist(c(2, 1, 4), c(4, 9, 8))
```

Comment: There is no need for `return`. Try: `euc_dist <- function(x1, x2) {sqrt(sum((x1 - x2)^2))}` will also work.

Comment: Agreed. Nevertheless, when writing more complex functions, I think it is helpful both for ourselves and other people re-using the code to make it clear what is each function returning. This is a simple case; in more complex functions, after three months, we may not remember what the function was supposed to return

Answer (score 5):

In addition to other answers, you can use `norm`:

```r
x1 <- c(2,1,4)
x2 <- c(4,9,8)
norm(as.matrix(x1 - x2), "F")
#R> [1] 9.165151
```

This is numerically stable as it ends up calling the `dlange()` LAPACK function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dist`:

```
dist(x)
#         1
#2 9.165151
```

or per hand using `apply` and `diff`

```
sqrt(sum(apply(x, 2, diff)^2))
#sqrt(sum((x[1,] - x[2,])^2)) #Alternative
#[1] 9.165151
```

Data:

```
x <- rbind(c(2,1,4), c(4,9,8))
```